# Get single random record from given categories in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, random, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in my database called `mcq-quiz` with 2000 records:

```
id  question    category
1   q1  c1
2   q2  c1
3   q3  c1
4   q4  c2
5   q5  c2
6   q6  c3
7   q7  c3
8   q8  c4
9   q9  c4
10  q10 c5
```

I want a single record from a given category... but the record should be random.

I have tried the following query:

```
 SELECT id, question, category  FROM `mcq_quiz` where category in(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) group by category
```

it is doing a good job, but retrieves the same records every time. But I want a new and random record every time.

I also have tried the `rand()` function, it retrieves the same records every time, but changes the sequence. But I need a random record everytime.

Comment: If this is your aim: "i want single record from given category" ... then a simple limit and random order works (given category being c1 in this example): `SELECT * FROM mcq_quiz WHERE category = 'c1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the greatest-n-per-group problem, where you want one random record per group.

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select q.*
from mcq_quiz q
where category in(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) and q.id = (
    select q1.id
    from mcq_quiz q1
    where q1.category = q.category
    order by rand()
    limit 1
)
```

Of, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select q.*, row_number() over(partition by category order by rand()) rn
    from mcq_quiz q
    where category in(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
) q
where rn = 1
```

Comment: this doesnot select questions from specific category... i want to get records from specific categoies only.. suppose i give 10 categories i want 10 questions to be returned. **where category in(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) **. and above codde retuen more than 1 question from 1 category

Comment: @ishitechMoga: you can just a `where` clause to the queries. See my edited answer.

Comment: its good , but it selects more than 1 record from single category and also not selects records from all categories... sometime it returns 9 rows, sometime 5 , sometime 4... i want fix number of rows to be returned, i.e. if i mention 10 cateories , then  10 rows everytime ... from all 10 categories